# connect to pod from outside (k8s)

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, service, kubernetes-ingress

I created a deployment file which runs some service.
The service uses port 7777.
I want to access the same service from the outside by typing the address x.x.x.x:7777.
I am attaching my deployment file which is currently working properly without service.
If I download the Ports part from the Deployment and apply to the service, nothing works.
I need to prepare a service file because I will soon connect more additional services that will each use the same IP address but on different ports.
What is the best way to work in order to achieve my goal?

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.7.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
  name: xyz
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy: {}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: xyz
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: xyz
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        node: w1
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: registry-secret1
      volumes:
        - name: zzz
          hostPath: 
            path: z/z/z
            type: DirectoryOrCreate
        - name: yyy
          hostPath: 
            path: y/y/y
            type: FileOrCreate
        - name: xxx
          hostPath: 
            path: x/x/x
            type: FileOrCreate
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: x
          value: "x"
        - name: y
          value: "y"
        name: quic-image
        image: "xxxyyyzzz"
        name: x-y-z
        volumeMounts: 
          - mountPath: x/x/x
            name: xxx
          - mountPath: y/y/y
            name: yyy
          - mountPath: z/z/z
            name: zzz
        ports:
          - containerPort: 7777
            hostPort: 7777
            protocol: UDP
          - containerPort: 7777
            hostPort: 7777
            protocol: TCP
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.7.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
  name: xyz
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: tcp
    port: 7777
  - protocol: UDP
    name: udp
    port: 7777
#    targetPort: 7777
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the service type  as nodeport as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert -f docker-compose.yml
    kompose.version: 1.7.0 (HEAD)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
  name: xyz
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: tcp
    port: 7777
    nodePort: 30077
  - protocol: UDP
    name: udp
    port: 7777
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: xyz
```

You can then access the service at HOSTNAME:30077

Comment: But I also want to use port 7777 from the outside

Comment: then you might want to consider binding the container port to HostPort. follow the link https://alesnosek.com/blog/2017/02/14/accessing-kubernetes-pods-from-outside-of-the-cluster/

Answer (score -1):

But I also want to use port 7777 from the outside